# Repositories and Methods

Tags: magento-2.1, methods, service-contract, repositories

Does anybody have a link where I can find a list of all Magento 2.1 (or Magento 2) repositories and their methods?

I tried to find this in Magento Devdocs and can't seem to find anything. Maybe I am looking under the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 0):

The code is often the best documentation:

1. Open https://github.com/magento/magento2/find/2.1
2. Type **Api/RepositoryInterface**
3. Browse